# Swapping numbers with their name from a list in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I am having a hard getting started on this question and was hoping somebody might be able to help with pseudocode or examples of similar problems. Thank you ahead of time!

Define a Scheme procedure *(swap-names lst)* which swaps each number 0-9 in the list with its name.

```
  For example: (swap-names '(2 4 8 5 0 4))   → (two four eight five zero four)
```

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to solve this. One idiomatic one would be to have a function that takes a list with the names and just picks the right one:

```
(define (number-name number)
  (if (< -1 number 10)
    (get-nth number '(zero one two three four five six seven eight nine))
    ('out-of-range)))

(define (get-nth number names)
  (if (equal? number 0)
    (car names)
    (get-nth (- number 1) (cdr names))))
```

And now just map this function over your list:

```
(define (swap-names digits)
   (map (lambda (d) (number-name d)) digits))
```

(This works on guile; I assume it would also work on Racket)

Answer (score 0):

In Scheme a vector is a data structure, which provides random access by an index. The literal syntax for vectors is `#(a b c)`. The function [`vector-ref`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._vector-ref%29%29) returns the element at the nth position. The function `map` iterates over lists and applies the given function to each element returning a list of the return values of the application.

```
(define (swap-names lst)
  (let ((digits #(zero one two three four five six seven eight nine)))
    (map (lambda (n)
           (vector-ref digits n))
         lst)))
```